# How to handle a wrong topic name in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume from a wrong or non-existent topic name using a Kafka consumer object.

And below is my log for that which comes after the polling line.

```
WARN 19508 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 22 : {dummyTopic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

It's only logging a warning in the console and is not throwing an exception. I want to handle this scenario. How to do so?
Below is my consumer code

```java
Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();

// Setting the consumerProperties object here and using
// it to create a consumer object
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties);
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = null;
try {
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
    consumer.listTopics();
    records = consumer.poll(100);
    LOGGER.info("Returning records to microservice.");
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {

    LOGGER.error("Illegal Argument Exception occurred while subscribing to topic by consumer. Message: " + illegalArgumentException.getMessage());
}
catch (KafkaException kafkaException) {
    LOGGER.error("Kafka Exception occurred while consuming records by consumer. Message: " + kafkaException.getMessage());
}
catch(Exception exception) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while creating consumer object " + exception);
}
```

How can I handle a non-existent topic name for a Kafka consumer? For Producer, it’s giving a timeout exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below-mentioned methods present in the Kafkaadmin utilities.

- Describe a given topic. [Link](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/DescribeTopicsResult.html). If it returns an exception then the topic does not exist.
- Get the list of all topics and find whether your topic exists in that list or not. [Link](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/ListTopicsResult.html)